# How to make a new List of ArrayList from a List of ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Another silly question from a complete beginner.

I have a `List<ArrayList<Boolean>> isExpenseByMonth` with the following contents:

`[[true, true, true, false, false, false], [true, true, false, false, false], [true, true, true, false, false, false]]`.

I need to "convert" boolean values to integers (true = -1, false = 1) and place them to a new `List<ArrayList<Integer>> boolToIntByMonth` so that it'd look like this (`ArrayList<Integer>`s should be of the same size as `ArrayList<Boolean>`s):

`[[-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1], [-1, -1, 1, 1, 1], [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1]]`

So far I've tried to play around with the following code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> boolToInt = new ArrayList<>();
//List<ArrayList<Integer>> boolToIntByMonth = new ArrayList<>();
        
for (ArrayList<Boolean> arr : isExpenseByMonth) {
    for (boolean b : arr) {
        if (b) {
            boolToInt.add(-1);
            //boolToIntByMonth.add(boolToInt);
        } else {
            boolToInt.add(1);
            //boolToIntByMonth.add(boolToInt);
        }
    }   
}
```

But the best I could get is this (one `ArrayList<Integer>` with the correct values and order):

`[-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has almost all the needed building blocks. The key missing part is creating a new `ArrayList<Integer>` in each iteration of the outer loop, like this:

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> boolToIntByMonth = new ArrayList<>();
for (ArrayList<Boolean> arr : isExpenseByMonth) {
    ArrayList<Integer> boolToInt = new ArrayList<>();
    boolToIntByMonth.add(boolToInt);
    for (boolean b : arr) {
        if (b) {
            boolToInt.add(-1);
        } else {
            boolToInt.add(1);
        }
    }   
}
```

Then you can use the `boolToIntByMonth` as a `List<ArrayList<Integer>>`:

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> result = boolToIntByMonth;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a **nested list** (`List<List<T>>`) at each step of iteration of the outer `for` loop you have to create a *new* `List` and populate it with the data for the current month inside the inner `for` loop. This *list* needs to be added into the resulting *nested list*.

```
    List<List<Integer>> intByMonth = new ArrayList<>();

    for (List<Boolean> arr : isExpenseByMonth) {
        List<Integer> nextMonth = new ArrayList<>();
        for (boolean b : arr) {
            nextMonth.add(b ? -1 : 1);
        }
        intByMonth.add(nextMonth);
    }
```

**Note:**

- Don't use concrete implementations like `ArrayList` as a type, it makes your code **inflexible** and unnecessarily verbose. Write the code against interfaces (`List`, `Map`, etc.). This approach is called [**Dependency inversion principle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

- stream the original list of lists
- then stream each list and map a boolean to the desired value.
- creating a list of lists

```
List<List<Boolean>> lists = List.of(
        List.of(true, true, true, false, false, false),
        List.of(true, true, false, false, false),
        List.of(true, true, true, false, false, false));

List<List<Integer>> result = lists.stream()
    .map(list -> list.stream().map(v -> v ? -1 : 1)
        .toList())
    .toList();

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
[-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1]
[-1, -1, 1, 1, 1]
[-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Note `v ? -1 or 1` says if `v` is true, use `-1` else use `1`.